# How to create a mirror website?

Tags: dns, web, mirroring, mirror

I would like to know how can we set up a mirror web site of a main web site ?
EG: Imagine that my domain is www.somedomain.com, someone is accessing to this domain. but that time the server is down/had some problems this time I need to redirect the user to another server. which have the same copy of main website. is it possible to redirect like this 
? I searched some forums i found that adding name server will redirect to mirror site but some people are saying this is not a good way to do this. can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your website's server is down, your server won't be able to redirect the visitors to the other site unless you put your redirection script (javascript) in the index page & you put the javascript on CDN.

However, even this method may not work if your site is not accessible due to DDoS attack.

"adding name server will redirect to mirror site but some people are saying this is not a good way to do this." - yes, this is not a good method as name server change takes up to 48 hours to be updated.

My above method is a better approach but that will only work if your server goes down for internal reason rather than an external issues such as DDoS attack.